# AngularJs directive not updating another directive's scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a parent directive that has a function that loads a modal div with data after a service call.  I have confirmed that the service correctly returns data, but that data model is never passed to the child directive's scope through the template.

Notice below that the parentDirective's scope.warrantymodel is set by the loadModal function.  Also notice that in the parent template, the "warrantymodel" should be mapped to the warrantyDirective's "model".

I've debugged through the code with chrome debugger and batarang, but the scope.$watch('model'...) call fires on page load but never fires after the button click loads the data.  I even tried the deep watch switch in the scope.$watch call (i.e. the "true" value).

```
app.directive('parentDirective', ["myService", function(myService){
   return {
      scope:{
          warranty: '=',
          ocode: '='
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: '/content/templates/parent.html',
        link: function(scope){
        scope.loadModal = function ($event) {
            //TODO: this gets data but it doesnt bind to the modal's model
            scope.warrantymodel = 
                  myService.getDataStuff(scope.warranty, scope.ocode);
    };
```

This is the child directive that should get the model:

```
app.directive('warrantyDirective', [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: '/content/templates/warranty.html',
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.$watch('model', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                         // this alert never fires after page load
                         // I have verified that the newValue has a value 
                         // and is different than the original value 
                         // (original value is undefined on page load)
                          alert("$watch model = " + newValue);

                          // do dom manipulation and other stuff
                      }, true);
```

The parent's template calls the warranty modal's directive like this:

```
<a data-ng-if="warranty" data-loading-text="Please wait..."  
   data-ng-click="loadModal($event)">{{ptext}}</a>

<div data-ng-if="warranty">
    <div warranty-directive model="warrantymodel"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas what's missing or how I can troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue:  I moved the loadModal function from the parent directive to the child, then moved the link that opens the modal div to the child directive's template.  From there, everything has direct access to the same scope.Model, etc. and the $watch works correctly.

It's strange that angular's "two-way binding" doesn't work with the $watch.  If anyone knows if that's by design or a bug, let me know in the comments.

Comment: I don't believe this is a bug as you can see it my demo, it works. I think in your case, when you click the link, the `loadModal` was not called. You need to post more HTML so that we know `which scope's loadModal` (parent,or warranty-directive) was called when we click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why you are using 2 directives?

It seems like, in this case it would be more straightforward to have a *controller* as the parent - handle adding the data from your service to its $scope, and pass the model you need from there into your warrantyDirective.

Or for that matter, you could use 0 directives to achieve the same result.
(ie. move all functionality out of the separate directives and into a single controller).

It doesn't look like you're doing any explicit DOM transformation here, so in this case, perhaps using 2 directives is overcomplicating things.

Alternatively, have a look at the Angular documentation for directives: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
The very last example at the bottom of the page explains how to wire up dependent directives.

Comment: I thought about moving the code to the top level controller, but the code is architected to have directive/templates within directive/templates several levels deep, so it seemed tricky to get the appropriate data.  The final directive is doing dom manipulation, but I left out those details (I updated my post with a code comment to clarify).  Thanks for the link I'll review the bottom section again.

Answer (score 0):

$watch fires only when the watched property **value** has changed. Even if you assign **another object** to the property with **the same value**, $watch **does not fire**

```
scope.loadModal = function ($event) {

   scope.warrantymodel = [1]; //use the same value every this function is fired.
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3H8ur/) (try clicking the "Click here" and watch the console)

When I assign a **different value** to the object, $watch fires:

```
scope.loadModal = function ($event) {
            var ran = Math.random(); //use random to assign a different value.
            scope.warrantymodel = [ran];
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3H8ur/1/) (try clicking the "Click here" and watch the console)

In your case, I think that the `getDataStuff` returns ***the same data*** every time you click load and $watch does not fire.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea, but I verified the original object is null (undefined) and the new object is a complete json object.  Thanks for the response though!

Comment: @Robert Corvus: $watch `always` fires the first time with 'undefined'. You could do a check like `if (newValue)` if you don't want to handle this value.

Comment: I do, the problem is that the watch never fires after the first time (i.e. the page load)